# How to write a function and call it in Katalon studio?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, katalon-studio

I am writing an automation script with Katalon studio and I wish to open a dropdown and select all the items in the dropdown and store them in a list(using xpath) and write a function to select options from the dropdown something similar to Selenium Webdriver implementation

```
public void selectDropdown(List<WebElement> ele, String value) throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < ele.size(); i++) {

            String option = ele.get(i).getText();
            if (option.contains(value)) {

                ele.get(i).click();
                break;
            }
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }

@FindBy(xpath="/html/body/div[14]/div/ul/li")
List<WebElement> listTemplateData;

public void selectTemplateField() throws InterruptedException
    {
        selectDropdown(listTemplateData, "Template3");
    }

public void testCase() throws InterruptedException {
        
        ResourceSchedulePage resourceSchedulePage = new ResourceSchedulePage(driver);

        resourceSchedulePage.selectTemplateField();
        logger.info("Template dropdown data is selected");
        Thread.sleep(500);
}
```

**How do I acheive the same in Katalon Studio?**

Answer (score 1):

User defined Keywords can be created in katalon and the same keyword can be called as part of the test step in testcase.

Reference : [https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/introduction-to-custom-keywords.html#:~:text=Create%20a%20Custom%20Keyword,Click%20OK](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/introduction-to-custom-keywords.html#:%7E:text=Create%20a%20Custom%20Keyword,Click%20OK).